# How to import .sql file into SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-express

I have a plain sql file with some SQL INSERT statements.

Is it possible to import it in my local SQL Server Express instance?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "import"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Management Studio Express edition. You can download the [latest version here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22985) - which will work against SQL Express 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2.

If you don't want to install SSMSE then you can use sqlcmd at a command prompt, e.g. something like this (assuming Windows auth and an instance called "SQLEXPRESS"):

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -E -i "C:\path\file.sql"
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be simply open the file in the Sql Management Studio and run it. Since the target table is already created, of course.

Comment: my file size is 1.3GB, the interface hangs... do you have any other GUI based method to import data

Answer (score 0):

You can open it via Query analyser and run

Comment: That was sooooooo last century - in SQL Server 2005 and up, it's Management Studio now ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tool [Sql_Server_Script_Executor](http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/Product/Sql_Server_Script_Executor.aspx)

[image]

You can add single/multiple file/folder and your files will comes up in the list. Click the execute button and done

```
It contains three transaction modes.
1. Execute scripts within one transaction
2. Execute scripts on separate transaction
3. No transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is open Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. 
Then use `File` -> `Open`.

Open the file from the proper location and you'll get all the SQL statements there. After that you can execute them.

Hope this helps.