# Deleted some GAC .dll files and problems with SQL

Tags: c#, sql, gac

I was having some problems with SQL Server Express 2008 as for some reason I had several conflicting versions.  I was told to go through and uninstall them, but I ended up installing all programs relating to SQL.  Now, a previously functioning windows service on VS2010 no longer compiles as it is missing its SQLCE reference, and I can't re-add it as it's not in the GAC.  How do I go about fixing this?

I think I'm a bit over my head with this task as I don't really have database experience.  I need to take an .sql file and import it into Microsoft SQL Server Express 2008.  Are there VERY beginner SQL tutorials to help me accomplish this?

Comment: Not really programming question so far: if you uninstall everything - consider installing some back. I.e. VS repair/install additional components could be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you end up having to uninstall all of it and reinstall, there is a specific order in which Visual Studio and SQL tools are best installed:

1. Visual Studio 2008
2. Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1
3. SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2008 R2
4. SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1 or SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1
5. Visual Studio 2010
6. Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1
7. SQL Server 2012

Note that for the Express editions of SQL there is no separate Service Pack. The Service Pack is integrated with the Express edition installer.

I see from the comments that you're already trying a repair install. Make sure that you reinstall the approriate Service Pack(S) after you complete the repair.

Comment: The repair has finished but I still can't locate System.Data.SqlServerCe

Comment: As a strictly "get it going" measure, you can try downloading from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5821 and installing Compact Edition from that. At some point it would probably be wise to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do some good searching before you post a question.  I googled "import .sql file into sql server 2008" and came up with some good entries in the top ten.

[How to import .sql file into SQL Server Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535532/how-to-import-sql-file-into-sql-server-express)

Comment: I did, I intalled Management Studio Express but it gave me conflicts and I had to uninstall it, along with some important .dlls...

Comment: Can you run the installation tool?  If so, you can probably use the Repair tool to help clean up your installation and retrieve the deleted DLLs.