# importing .sql file in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

please, i want to import database in sql server from .sql file using visual studio 2013.
i've tried this command :

```
source fileLocation\file.sql
go
```

but i'm getting the error :

```
erreur is Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '\'.
```

sql file :

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [SomeDatabaseName]
CONTAINMENT = NONE
ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = 'SomeDatabaseName', FILENAME = N'C:\FilePath\SomeDatabaseName.mdf'  
,SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
LOG ON 
...
```

Comment: And what do you expect the `source` keyword to do? That is a MySQL command.

Comment: what to do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is here [How to import .sql file into SQL Server Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535532/how-to-import-sql-file-into-sql-server-express?rq=1)

if is not working open new query and  copy content of file.sql in it